# Bundled JS at Home/Scripts/js after deployed to Azure with ASP.NET MVC 4

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an ASP.NET MVC 4 web application. All my JS files are in the Script folder. I am bundling them all like this:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/Scripts/js").IncludeDirectory("~/Scripts", "*.js"));
```

In Views/Shared I have _BootstrapLayout.basic.cshtml, with this call to the bundle:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I have had it in the body and the head, and it makes no difference.
When I run it locally in debug mode, it works just fine. When I deploy it, it does not work, and shows the following in the Chrome Console:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)  http://mysite.azurewebsites.net/Home/scripts/js
```

"mysite" is the name of my website on Azure.

Since the bundle is made to ~/Scripts/js, it will not find anytning in /Home/scripts/js. How do I fix this?

UPDATE I:

The reference issue has been fixed, thanks to @jamoerdyk's answer below. The script bundle should be included like this:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/js")
```

Now, I still get an error and the scripts are not working. The Chrome Console looks like this:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token * /scripts/js?v=fIEoVL9cKX9p8_aBxRN9dMr1OHqh5ZMjO7E8iZ7Z3hQ1:12
```

Any ideas? Or is it not related at all?

UPDATE II:

The minification was failing - that was the second problem. So I stopped using bundling for a while, and make regular src-references to the scripts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be including your script bundle like this:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/js")
```

instead of your

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: I was a little too quick to mark that as the whole answer. But it certainly solved the reference issue - thank you. It still does not work once deployed, giving this in the Chrome Console: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token * /scripts/js?v=fIEoVL9cKX9p8_aBxRN9dMr1OHqh5ZMjO7E8iZ7Z3hQ1:12

Comment: Difficult to say without your View code where the @Scripts.Render is included and/or the generated HTML from the browser.

Comment: Answers the first part of the question. Please see the second part of the question in the update - problem has to do with minification.

Comment: I can't see your linked page from my current location because of content filtering.